# How to change x:Name property inside xaml code using c# script?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xaml, maui

### Problem:

Using code need to add the XAML x:Name property to my ShellContentItem, that I'm creating inside AppShell.

### Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: first, please do NOT post code as images.  Second, `Name` is not an actual property that you can modify at runtime.  They are just XAML helpers that are turned into variable names during compilation.  If you explained what you were actually trying to accomplish by doing this we might be able to help you

Comment: @Jason okay,I understood you

Comment: @Jason I need to get access to a single object using this XAML property, If you have any ideas on how to realize it in other ways, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding an element in c#, you don't "create an x:Name". Instead, you simplify define a property, and set that property to the element.

```cs
private ShellContent myItem;

    // Inside your method
    myItem = new ShellContent();
...
```

Now you access `myItem` like any other property.

---

If you wish to create and access a collection of items, you do that like any other kind of object in c#:

```cs
private List<ShellContent> myItems;

    // In method.
    myItems = new List<ShellContent>();
    for (...)
    {
        var item = new ShellContent();
        myItems.Add(item);
    }
```

Now access one like any other list: `myItems[...]`.